Invalid maximum heap size -Xmx0m while initializing hail in python
I am trying to initialize hail using the following command:
import hail as hl
hl.init()

but I get the error below.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256M
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256M
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx0m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
any suggestion how to deal with this error?
I have already tried to set the environment variable to set -Xmx but still I get the same error as you can see in the error message.
